# How do I make my checkbox in my code default to unchecked before a selection is made while keeping my functionality the same?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, jsx, checked

Right now I have numberical logic that stores the numbrer value for the selection chosen. I would like to keep it that way. For whatever reason, the checkbox is always by default checked on the first option by default

```
 let labels = ['Staff', 'Customers'];

    // index 2 is web alert banner for staff
    // index 3 is web alert banner for customers
    if (this.props.channelIndex === 2 || this.props.channelIndex === 3) {
      labels = ['Staff (Hub)', 'Customers (Public Site)'];
    }
const channelTypeIndex = this.props.channelIndex % 2 === 0 ? this.props.channelIndex : this.props.channelIndex - 1;
 return (
      <div className="widget comm-type-selector">
        <div className="comm-label">1. Choose your audience and message format </div>
        <div>
          {labels.map((opt, i) => {
            return (
              <div className="rec-form-check-wrap" key={`${opt}-key`}>
                <label
                  htmlFor={opt}
                  className="rec-label-radio">
                  <input
                    id={opt}
                    className="rec-input-hide comm-channel-type-picker"
                    type="radio"
                    name={`${opt}-input`}
                    checked={this.props.channelIndex === channelTypeIndex + i}
                    onChange={() => this.props.setChannelIndex(channelTypeIndex + i)} />
                  <span className="rec-input-radio" />
                  {opt}
                </label>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an instance where state and props worked the same way seen here http://react.tips/checkboxes-in-react/